# How to run this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have following code in asp.net

```
 <html>
   <head runat="server">
<title>Turn page</title>

<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/turn.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });
</script>
</head>

  <body>
    <div id="flipbook">
       <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
          <div class="hard"></div>
             <div> Page 1 </div>
             <div> Page 2 </div>
             <div> Page 3 </div>
             <div> Page 4 </div>
             <div class="hard"></div>
             <div class="hard"></div>
          </div>

      </body>
  </html>
```

I am supposed to get this desired effect [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blasten/A9a7E/)

but I am unable to run the code.What am I missing ??

Thanks

Comment: you should add your scriot in dom ready handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the script inside `document.ready` as shown below. `document.ready` will ensure that all DOM structure is ready now and you can apply script to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$(document).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Code included inside `$(window).load(function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flipbook").turn({
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            autoCenter: true
        }); 
    });
</script>
```